# mistake when i try deploy Rails app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems

rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

Comment: Do you have the pg gem in your gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

gem 'pg' needs to be in your Gemfile. If you are using sqlite3 in development, put gem 'pg' in your production group (within the group :production block). Otherwise, gem 'pg' just needs to be in the gemfile anywhere outside of the :development group is fine. Don't forget to bundle install, push your changes to git and redeploy.

Comment: All thanks, I find my mistake, I'm incorrectly installed my application in first step.